# How this regular expression do this?

Tags: java, regex

I want to use below expression in my program but i don't know what do this regular expression!
please help me.

```
"(?=(?!^)[,;.:])|(?<=[,;.:])"
```

in the above expression (?=(?!^)[,;.:]) find any character set that end with [.;,:] or no? what do this (?!^) in this expression?
and this expression find any character set that end with [,;.:] or no?
please help me.

Comment: Why do you want to use it if you don't know what it does?

Comment: because i want to split a string and this regex can do this!

Comment: like this string aa ,. 1. .a. that splitted into below characters
[aa] [,] [.] [1] [.] [.] [a] [.] and i don't know how this regex can do this

Comment: So you know what it does - you just need help to understand **how** it does it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression matches 0-length strings that satisfy one of these two conditions:

- Ahead of it is one of `,;.:`, but not for 0-length strings just before the beginning of the subject string (position 0). So the subject string `"."` has no match at position 0, only at position 1 because of the following alternative. This is done with positive lookahead (?=) and negative lookahead (?!).
- Behind it is one of `,;.:`. This is done with positive lookbehind (?<=).

For instance for `"aaa,1"`, you have two matches: at position three (after the last `a`, because it's followed by `,`) and at position 4  (because it's preceded by `,`).

Comment: so why aa can splited? 
because aa hasn't any of [,;.:]!! but splited!

Comment: Ahead of aa isn't any of [.,:;] and aa doesn't end with [.,;:]! but splited!

Comment: @taher `aa` is not split. The match is only after `aa`. That's why the two `a`s are not separated.

Comment: @taher Ah I didn't see the space. `aa .` is split into `aa ` and `.`. I think you're seeing the space, but it's there.

Comment: @taher `aa .,; 123 a1. 1. .a.` is split into 12 parts: `aa §.§,§;§ 123 a1§.§ 1§.§ §.§a§.§` with the matched positions indicated by `§`. I'm not sure what else you are expecting/getting.

Comment: please see below example when i want to split a string like this
aa .,; 123 a1. 1. .a. 
i use String.next( ) in my code to send above string to a func that use above expression to split it with [;,.:] and doesn't clean the [,.;:] from split string because i want to know delimiters in my code.
one better things in this expression is that erase "" from splited string because when "" doesn't split my func can't recognize it and send unknown character. in the above expression (?!^) do this but i don't know what is this!!!

Comment: @taher (?!^) is a negative lookbehind matching the begging of the string; the "but" part in the first bullet of my answer.

Comment: This is my program out put but i don't know what do this expression do?
i do't know what is lookbehind!!
my program out put is
<del .>
<var aa>
<del .>
<num 123>
<del ;>
<del .>
<del ,>
<del ;>
<del :>
<num 1>
<unknown 6U>
<var x>
<var y>
<var z>
<unknown @32>
<num +58>
<num -40>
<var variable>
<del ;>
String is : . aa .123;  .,;: 1 6U x y z 
@32 +58 -40 variable;

Comment: why aa . can splited where aa doesn't start with any of [,;.:] or ended with[.,;:]?
in aa . {aa} doesn't one of [.,;:] or doesn't have one of [,.;:] in look behind!!